# Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

Tags: r, algorithm

I run this code yesterday and it worked however after running today, I got this error. 
Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

```
library(rattle)
dsname <- "weatherAUS"
ds <- get(dsname)
p <- ggplot(ds, aes(Location, fill=Location))
p <- p + geom_bar(width=1, colour="white")
p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")
p <- p + coord_flip()
p <- p + geom_text(stat="bin",
color="white",
hjust=1.0,
size=3,
aes(y=..count.., label=..count..))
```

I was wondering how I can fix this problem.

Comment: why aren't you just doing `ggplot(weatherAUS, aes(Location, fill=Location))`? can you `dput` that data frame so the question is reproducible? What changed since yesterday, did you update `ggplot2`?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, yes, I update all packages, I run this code yesterday and I got a nice plot however when I run it today I get this error. if you install rattle, you can get the data set!!

Comment: you should read up on ggplot2 2.0. there are many changes. upgrading without reviewing the changes was prbly not a good idea. also, i really don't need gtk+ on my OS X system (it's a `rattle` dependency).

Comment: also, did you try changing `geom_text(stat="bin"…)` to `stat="count"`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Yes, now, it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per my comment, it's never a good idea to `update.packages` or even `install.package` for new versions of things without checking what may potentially break. ggplot2 2.0 has some core differences that Hadley has been really good about communicating.

Here's a working version of the code:

```
library(rattle)
library(ggplot2)

data(weatherAUS)

p <- ggplot(weatherAUS, aes(Location, fill=Location))

# using geom_bar will automatically make a new "count" column
# available in an internal, transformed data frame. the help
# for geom_bar says as much

p <- p + geom_bar(width=1, colour="white")

# geom_text can then access this computed variable with
# ..count.. (I still thin that's horrible syntax, hadley :-)
p <- p + geom_text(aes(y=..count.., label=..count..),
                   stat="count", color="white",
                   hjust=1.0, size=3)

p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")
p <- p + coord_flip()
p

# to be more explicit to other readers of your code, you
# could also do this instead of the `geom_bar` call
p <- p + stat_count(width=1, colour="white", geom="bar")
```

[image]

Unless this is just for practicing ggplot2, coloring each of those bars uniquely is probably not a good idea for "production" visualizations.

Comment: This is a great answer because it's so detailed, but .. what exactly broke from the questioner's code? I haven't spotted it.

Comment: ggplot2's API changed.

Comment: Sure, but which part of the API changed such that they got that error? Which geom, which stat? I am getting the same error, but when I run it line by line it doesn't break, so I'm looking for clues.